# Selenium Webdriver (Java) cannot click the AJAX button

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a website with some buttons on the top. 
When clicked, a new AJAX section will appear.

I am not too familiar with HTML, but the button "Add" (this button is my target) is somehow located in `<span>`.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html slick-uniqueid="3">
<head></head>
<body class="newui">
    <div class="pagewrapper ">
        <div class="section shadow" data-form-element="SectionHeading">
            <div class="section-header">
                <div class="section-title"></div>
                <div class="section-nav">
                    <ul>
<li class="add u-yellow">
<span></span>
<span style="background-color: transparent;">
    Add
</span>
```

I use this code in Selenium

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[5]/span[2]")).click();
```

but Selenium cannot find that button nor click it.

It return error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1776, 32). Other element would receive the click: 
>     (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.115)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 51 milliseconds

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no button in your span section? Do you want to simply click the text "add"?

Comment: There is a button with "Add" text on it. When that "Add" button is clicked, it will load a small AJAX section.

Comment: I had some successes with the JavascriptExecutor click method in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that the `li` element is actually clickable:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.add.u-yellow")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution. 
Basically I used FirePath (Firefox Add-on) to find the CSS or XPath location and use it for my webdriver code. 
Firepath told me that the button has CSS location

`.add.u-yellow>span`

and I put it in my code

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".add.u-yellow>span")).click();`

... It works :)

I am not familiar with Javascript ,so I don't know why `.add.u-yellow>span` works. But FirePath seems to be a good tool to assists Webdriver developer :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lot of things.

1. The element is not in the visible view port of the web browser
2. The page has not finished loading
3. The element is behind another element

You can try to click on the parent element as someone else already suggested:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.add.u-yellow")).click();
```

Alternatively, you can bind the class of the span element:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[style='background-color: transparent;']")).click();
```